# As imagens não aparecem na caixa de entrada Mail. Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Existe um formulário de contato onde o usuário manda uma mensagem para o sistema e o sistema automaticamente manda uma mensagem de volta agradecendo seu contato e junto com a mensagem eu mando os artigos mais visualizados.
O que acontece é que no meu hotmail (na minha maquina aparece as imagens), mais na conta de outra pessoa não aparece as imagens do logo tipo do sistema e nem as imagens dos artigos mais visualizados. Como resolver esse problema.Veja como estou fazendo.
Controller:

```
$artigo = Postagem::with('departamentos')->where('status', true)->orderByDesc('visualizacao')->paginate($this->paginate);

Mail::send('frontend.email.contato.contato-mensagem' , ['artigos' =>  $artigo , 'contato'   =>  $request] , function($message){
            $message->to($_REQUEST['email']);
            $message->subject('Contatos Igreja de Deus em Luziania');
        });
```

view:(Vou mostrar somente a parte que interessa)

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
            <p>Prezado(a) {{$contato->nome}}, queremos agradecer seu contato, sua participação foi muito importante para nós.
                Aproveitamos para reforçar nosso compromisso e lhe atender logo em breve.
                Obrigado.
                <br>
                <a href="{{url('/')}}">Igreja de Deus no Brasil </a> Ainda há lugar.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <h3>Artigos Mais visualizados</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    @foreach($artigos as $artigo)
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
                <ul class=""><a href="{{url('/')}}/artigos/get/{{$artigo->id}}"
                                class="media-box post-image"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <img
                                src="{{url('/')}}/imagens/artigo/{{$artigo->imagem}}" alt="" class="img-thumbnail"
                                width="100" height="100"> </a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-blog-content"><a
                        href="{{url('/')}}/artigos/get/{{$artigo->id}}">{{$artigo->titulo}}</a></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <article>
                        <p>{!! substr($artigo->descricao , 0 ,150) !!} ..</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

No @foreach, ele faz um loop dos artigos mais visualizados. Agora as imagens não aparecem. Se caso estiver errado por gentileza diga-me o que eu tenho que fazer, pois eu sou iniciante.

Comment: Não vejo nenhuma `<img src="...">` , tens a certeza que existe? E o url da imagem está certo?

Comment: O problema pode estar no endereço da imagem, você pode estar usando uma *URL relativa ao lugar em que o arquivo está* sendo que deveria estar usando uma *URL absoluta* Ex: `<img src="//meudominio.com/imgs/teste.png" />`

Comment: No meu hotMail aparece as imagens já no hot mais de outra maquina não aparece as imagens. Acho que esta acontecendo o seguinte. Na minha maquina ele consegue acessar o servidor localhost mais na outra maquina não consegue pq o sistema e local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do seu src coloque o caminho da imagem conforme o exemplo abaixo:

src="{{ $message->embed(url('/') . '/imagens/artigo/' . $artigo->imagem)}}"

Comment: Pv Telles Por que do seu jeito deu certo e do meu jeito não deu certo?
Como assim Essa obj $message veio parar na minha view?